# How do i write video to iphone camera roll using AVFoundation?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, nsurl, avcapturesession

I am currently recording video using AVFoundation api and have specified a fileUrl to write to:

```
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"]];
```

However, right now its recording to a temp directory. How do i write this file to the camera roll? Whats the camera roll directory?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the AVCamDemo from the WWDC 2010 sessions. It shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some documentation on Apples site from the AVCamDemo code.

Comment: Hi! Maybe you could extend your answer to provide a link to where you found the solution and maybe the code snippet that fixed your issue? That way you can help others who have a similar question :)

Comment: Why is it the right answer? There is no code or link or explanation.

Answer (score 3):

After recording to the disk do the following to copy the video to Camera Roll

```
if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outFileName)) {
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outFileName, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
}
```

Note that UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum() will be successful only of the recorded video is proper QuickTIme format.